# Start Workflow with powershell cancels right away

Tags: workflow, powershell

I have this script to run a workflow on a list of items. It starts the workflow, but it just goes straight to cancelled without actually running it. Am I missing something? If I run the workflow manually, it works.

I know it's not going into the workflow as I have some logging there that is not getting into the history log.

```
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$sourceWebURL  = "http://intranet/finance"
$sourceSiteURL = "http://intranet"
$sourceListName = "Purchase Request Tracker";
$sourceWorkflow = "Purchase Request Tracker Workflow"

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges( { 
    #Site and List  
    $SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment 
    $web = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment 
    $site = Get-SPSite $sourceSiteURL

})


#List Name  
$list = $web.Lists[$sourceListName]; 

#Workflow Manager
$manager=$site.WorkFlowManager
$association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($sourceWorkflow, "en-US")
$association.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$association.AllowManual = $true

#Iterate through all Items in List and all Workflows on Items.  
#Filtered List
Write-Host "Restarting workflows.."
foreach ($item in $list.Items) { 
    if ($item["Status"] -like "*Pending") {
        Write-Host "$sourceWorkflow started on " $item.Name
        $data=$association.AssociationData
        $wf=$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data,$true)
        #$item.Update()
    }
}

Write-Host Finished.
$web.Dispose() 
$site.Dispose()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to use impersonation step in powershell script, if I assume you are running the script with System Account.

You cannot trigger workflows using system account. You can check below poweshell script to impersonate web object using user ID

```
$user=$web.AllUsers.GetByID(1073741823)
$token = $user.UserToken;
$impWebObj= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $token);
$imperWeb = $impWebObj.OpenWeb();
```

Reference: [Powershell and Sharepoint: Impersonation](http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.in/2011/04/powershell-and-sharepoint-impersonation.html)

Comment: I did find my error and it is permission related. I have 2 accounts and I was running the script from the wrong account. But this is interesting, so ill take a look. Is there a way to run it as the sharepoint\system account?

Comment: Na..as per my understanding and knowledge you cannot run designer workflows using System Account..

Comment: seems to have worked for me